# Why the horizontal spacing is removed in a subsection when using special characters?

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to add a special symbol to a subsection of the document, but it appears from what read online "PDF standard doesn't support special symbols in bookmarks". I found the answer and someone suggested to use `\texorpdfstring{}`. It worked, but I also wanted the symbol to be displayed in the bold letter so used the `\bm{}` package. It works but when I compile it removes space from the next characters as shown in the image below. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
\section{Case 1 \texorpdfstring{\bm{$\alpha}$} is kept constant}
```

[image]

Comment: \texorpdfstring has two arguments, you forgot the second one.

Comment: Change `\section{Case 1 \texorpdfstring{\bm{$\alpha}$} is kept constant}` to `\section{Case 1 \texorpdfstring{$\bm{\alpha}$}{alpha} is kept constant}`. Observe that `\bm` should be used in math mode.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated!!

Comment: What is the correct way to highlight text in a non-math mode? is that`\boldsymbol{}` the right approach in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the commande `\texorpdfstring` take two arguments,
So you should be add the `{}` at the last of the command to make you sure that the rest of the command not combined with the text in the section, like the suggestion below.

```
\section{Case 1 \texorpdfstring{\bm{$\alpha$}}{} is kept constant}
```

Result :

[image]

Good luck

Comment: Unless you want to make hyperbookmark entry nearly incomprehensible, you shouldn't leave the second argument of `\texorpdfstring` empty. Also, it should be `$\bm{\alpha$}`, not `\bm{$\alpha$}`. (`\bm` is short for "bold math".)